# Pubnub PHP Subscribe Function

Tags: php, html, subscribe, pubnub

I need major help!

I am having troubles getting the Pubnub subscribe function to work with PHP! I can get the publish function to work, but not the subscribe function. I have copied some code straight from the Pubnub site, but I am not getting anything. Any help? Also, my PHP version is 5.2.*.

Code:

```
<?
include("Pubnub.php");
$pubnub = new Pubnub(
    "not showing you",  // PUBLISH_KEY
    "not showing you",  // SUBSCRIBE_KEY
    "",      // SECRET_KEY
    false    // SSL_ON?
);
$pubnub->subscribe(array(
'channel' => 'Chat',
'callback' => create_function(
    '$message',
    'var_dump($message); return true;'
    )
));
?>
```

Comment: We can't fix what we can't see, and definitely can't diagnose what you don't provide ANY details for. "doesn't work" is useless.

Comment: It just gives me random errors that don't make any sense at all. I will add in some code I am trying to fix.

Comment: Maybe those errors don't make any sense to you, but they will have some meaning and would help diagnose the problem. Please post them as well.

Comment: 90% of the time I get 'Bad Response From Server', 5% of the time I get 'Missing Channel', and the other 5% of the time I get a blank page, even after I sent a value. You can go here to see for yourself. http://scriptersunited.comeze.com/PubnubTest.php

Answer (score 2):

> **⚠️ ALERT: SDK has been upgraded ⚠️**
>
> New SDK URL: https://github.com/pubnub/php

You are asking about a way to use the Subscribe method within a web server like Apache using PHP as the dynamic processing language.  Note that this is not a good practice and generally not necessary to do.  You would not use the **Subscribe({...})** method in a request/response.

The correct way to utilize the **$pubnub->subscribe(...)** method is in a long-lived PHP process, not involving a web server request-response model.  Here are some examples that are confirmed to work:

https://github.com/pubnub/php

Note that each example is assumed to be in a solitary PHP process **outside** of a web server like Apache when using the **Subscribe** API in PHP.  However!  The **Publish()** API can be used anywhere, including an Apache web server.

**Reading History w/ Apache PHP**

As an alternative you will be happy to take advantage of our HISTORY API.  You can query messages in the Queue with this and receive messages.  Here is an example PHP History API usage:

```
<?php

## Capture Publish and Subscribe Keys from Command Line
$publish_key   = "YOUR_PUBLISH_KEY";
$subscribe_key = "YOUR_SUBSCRIBE_KEY";

## Require Pubnub API
require('../Pubnub.php');

## -----------------------------------------
## Create Pubnub Client API (INITIALIZATION)
## -----------------------------------------
$pubnub = new Pubnub( $publish_key, $subscribe_key );

## Get History
echo("Requesting History...\n");
$messages = $pubnub->history(array(
    'channel' => 'hello_world', ## REQUIRED Channel to Send
    'limit'   => 100            ## OPTIONAL Limit Number of Messages
));
var_dump($messages);            ## Prints Published Messages.

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using history right now, as it is very useful. I guess I will just stick with my JavaScript subscribe right now. I will find some way to get my script working with what I need to do!

Comment: The link you have provided is dead, is there an alternative to it?

Answer (score 1):

The php subscribe function is broken and will be fixed in a new upcoming api, I talked with support recently about this and they gave me the this information.